Minikube Zero Downtime Deployment
How can I achieve a zero-downtime deployment with a Minikube? I have a Spring Boot app with an exposed health endpoint:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus,health
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.redis.enabled=false


This is my deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-boot-k8s
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-boot-k8s
          image: springboot-k8s-demo:3.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

How can i ensure that my app is available all the time during a deployment?
